# Postgresql connecting issue with pgjdbc-ng

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, pgjdbc-ng

I am trying to connect postgresql with [pgjdbc-ng](https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng)(0.8.9) for asynchronous listener. Everything work fine when developing, but I got connect timeout in SIT environment.

There is a postgresql 13 server in SIT, force client connect with ssl, use tls 1.3 only.

Here is the code:

```java
@Bean
public PGConnection getPGConnection() throws SQLException {
    var connectionString = String
        .format("jdbc:pgsql://%s/%s?ssl.mode=require", host, database);
    return DriverManager
            .getConnection(connectionString, user, password)
            .unwrap(PGConnection.class);
}
```

And here is the stacktrace print out:

```
Cause by: java.io.IOException: Timeout starting connection
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory.startup
    ...
```

---

It confuses me because only the connection from above code got timeout error. **Other connections of Spring Data JAP(PostgreSQL JDBC Driver) are totally correct in same application at same time.** And the worst is I can't reproduce in my enviroment.

At first I thought it was about tls protocol verison because the application need to work on  a mechine which openssl version in 1.0.1(tls 1.3 is not supported). But it seens not because other connections work properly.

I kown it was not rejected from connection limit for postgres user because it throw different exception. And I've tried use different way to get connection like:

```java
var dataSource = new PGDataSource();
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:pgsql://host/dbname");
dataSource.setUser(user);
dataSource.setPassword(password);  
dataSource.setSslMode(SSLMode.Require.name());
var conn = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(PGConnection.class);
```

It turned into same result, work in developing and fail in SIT environment.

---

Dose anybody has similar experiences?

Or please tell me what should I check with DBA, `pg_hba.conf` or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your SSL enabled postgres server in SIT environment using psql? Also, are you using Docker?
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/ssl.html

Comment: @nulldroid Thanks for your comment. I can't connect with psql because the verison of psql is too low to support tls 1.3. But I'm sure other connections from PostgreSQL JDBC Driver connect with SSL enabled. And No, there are no Docker in SIT.

Answer (score 1):

I was in (what I think is) a similar situation.

I have one `HikariDataSource` for connections to the database which works fine both locally and on the dev environment and one `PGDataSource` (from pgjdbc-ng) which works locally but timeouts on the dev environment (I am also using it for NOTIFY/LISTEN).

Turns out the problem was due to insufficient numbers. Specifically the remote environment is a k8s cluster which starts docker containers. Apparently there is not enough entropy in docker containers so a call to `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextInt()` blocks since it uses `/dev/random`, because this is the default algorithm chosen by Java.

The proper fix would be to configure the docker containers to provide enough entropy for `/dev/random` not to hang, however right now I am using a workaround by setting `Security.setProperty("securerandom.strongAlgorithms", "NativePRNG")` at startup which makes Java choose a non-blocking algorithm for `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()`.